# Is it possible to see more than 65536 rows in Excel 2007?

Tags: excel

I have an excel file which has more than 65536 rows. However, I can see only first 65536 of them. Is it possible to see all of them in Excel 2007?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here is an interesting [blog entry about numbers / limitations of Excel 2007](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2005/09/26/474258.aspx). According to the author the new limit is approximately **one million rows**.

Sounds like you have a **pre-Excel 2007 workbook open in Excel 2007 in compatibility mode** (look in the title bar and see if it says compatibility mode). If so, the workbook has 65,536 rows, not 1,048,576. You can save the workbook as an Excel workbook which will be in Excel 2007 format, close the workbook and re-open it.

Comment: I can't found the blog entry. :/

Comment: @kame Oh, they boke the link. Here's another link with hopefully similar content: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/arvinwu/archive/2008/10/02/some-excel-2007-limitation.aspx

Comment: 'close the workbook and re-open it' after saving as .xlsx is an important step!

Answer (score 10):

According to [this MSDN entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2005/09/26/474258.aspx), the limit is 1 million rows.  You could be running in compatibility mode, which would limit you to the old standard of 65k.  Does your excel say compatibility mode in the title?  If so, you can save the file as a new style file under the "save as" menu, or change your default to always use the 2007 file standard.

Comment: Yes, it says "compatibility mode".

But "save as" in xslx doesn't work, because new file will only have 65536 rows saved, so all following rows that were in original file will be lost.

Can I open the old file without compatibility mode?

Comment: it doesn't make sense that the old file was an xls with more than 65k rows... Could it be an comma delimited file, csv filetype?  If so, change your default to the xslx format, and then I believe you'll be able to open the old file in the new style. If it was xls, what generated the file? Not Excel!

Answer (score 2):

I have found that the 65536 limit still applies to pivot tables, even in Excel 2007.

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure where all of the other suggestions are trying to go, but the issue is basically related to the extension that you have on the file. If you save the file as a Excel 97/2003 workbook it will not allow you to see all million rows. Create a new sheet and save it as a workbook and you will see all million. Note: the extension will be .xlsx

Answer (score 2):

Excel 2003, doesn't included 1M row features, Introduced in 2007 onwards.

In Excel2007, save as "normal" Excel file, not a backwards compatible one.

You may have to close and re-open Excel to get the full 1M rows

Thilip

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the new limit is approximately 1 million rows.

http://blogs.msdn.com/excel/archive/2005/09/26/474258.aspx