# Excel Export Fail when Number of rows in the Excel sheet exceeded the limit of 65536 rows ssrs

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services, ssrs-tablix, ssrs-grouping

In SSRS 2008 (I use Sql Server BIDS to create reports) how to solve "Excel Export Fail when Number of rows in the Excel sheet exceeded the limit of 65536 rows ssrs" issue

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Yes, this is a limitation of SSRS through 2008R2.

SSRS 2012, included with SQL server 2012 will remove this limit:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2012/02/01/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-reporting-services-in-sql-server-2012-codename-quot-denali-quot-will-support-xlsx-docx-formats-bye-bye-65536-rows-limit-in-xls-files.aspx

The workaround for 2008R2 and before is to export as .csv

Answer (score 4):

When your results are exceeding 65k rows (and you dont have SSRS2012), create a parent group on the tablix (or table, or list) and in the `Group on:` field enter the expression below.

Add Page break between each instance of a group

```
 =CInt(Ceiling(RowNumber(nothing)/65000))
```

Answer (score 0):

I think some Excel Versions can not support more then 65536 rows per se. You might consider to expand the data on several worksheets / tables.

A similar Issue is discussed here:
[Is it possible to see more than 65536 rows in Excel 2007?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197762/is-it-possible-to-see-more-than-65536-rows-in-excel-2007)

Answer (score 0):

If your report is simple enough you can export as CSV, then import into Excel.

Answer (score 0):

1. Export that data to csv file first.
2. then open a new Excel 2010 blank workbook.
3. Click file and open the exported csv file.
4. it will give you a Text Import Wizard prompt.
5. Continue clicking Next and then Finish.
6. If there is data that you need to keep as text ensure that in Step 3 of 3 you click Text for each column that you want to keep leading zeros if any.