# Exporting to Excel in SSRS getting error when it crosses 65,000 rows

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

Exporting to Excel in SSRS getting error when it crosses 65,000 rows

I am using ssrs (BIDS) to create reports, I struck in exporting to excel when it crosses 65,000 rows. how to solve this problem in ssrs reports

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel Export Fail when Number of rows in the Excel sheet exceeded the limit of 65536 rows ssrs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682170/excel-export-fail-when-number-of-rows-in-the-excel-sheet-exceeded-the-limit-of-6)

Answer (score 1):

Are you exporting as an .xlsx file? I know in pre-2007 Excel (.xls) the maximum row count was about 65,000.

Comment: currently i am exporting to .xls

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer and I hope this is the another way to solve the above problem

generate sql table like this

col1 col2 grp

1    2     1

2    3     1

4    5     1

2    4     2

4    5     2

and give group by column as "grp" and make visiblility false for grp textbox in ssrs report. also in page breaks properties check the "between each instance of a group" checkbox. when you exprot to excel the data will come in differnt sheets for diffetent groups.

user this link for query - [Increase row count in sql server after some count (say 25,000)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9733642/increase-row-count-in-sql-server-after-some-count-say-25-000)

Answer (score 0):

That's an excel 2003 limitation and SSRS does not support excel 2007.
You need to export to csv or add groups on your report (with 65k max rows) so each group will be exported as on sheet on the excel document