# Increase row count in sql server after some count (say 25,000)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table like this

```
col1 col2 col3
3   5    8    
4   5    5    
5   5    5    
3   3    3    
4   5    6
```

I need to get table like below in SQL Server

```
col1 col2 col3  group 
  3   5    8    1
  4   5    5    1
  5   5    5    2
  3   3    3    2
  4   5    6    3
```

After some row count (say 25000 ) group column row count has to increase

(ex- if row count crosses 25,000 the group column value has to change to next number ie 25,001 - 2, 50001 - 3)

How to write a query in SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) to generate numbers and the do some calculations.
This will make on group of 5 rows.

```
select Column1, 
       Column2,
       1 + ((row_number() over(order by Column3) - 1) / 5)
from YourTable
```