# ssrs report issue while exporting to excel

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I am working on SSRS. I have created a report that contains 80,000 rows. When I run this report on my local server, it is working fine. When I convert the report to Excel, it is taking a long time, the file is getting corrupted, and I am unable to open it.

Additionally, once the report has been deployed to report server, if I try to export to Excel, it is showing a runtime error.

Comment: Adding more detail to this question will likely get you an answer faster. Please edit your question and add the error messages you are getting.

Answer (score 2):

You are exceeding the number of allowable rows for Excel exporting:

[Excel Export Fail when Number of rows in the Excel sheet exceeded the limit of 65536 rows ssrs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682170/excel-export-fail-when-number-of-rows-in-the-excel-sheet-exceeded-the-limit-of-6)

Which unfortunately limits to 65536 rows.

You can export to CSV and then bring it into Excel. Also, I haven't tested this since I don't have an SSRS 2008 R2 instance available, but you might be able to add page breaks every 50,000 rows and then try to export to Excel.

Answer (score 0):

You can paginate the report and break it up so that it displays on multiple sheets.  I've done this on a few of my reports that show 100K+ line items.  But that will be your only option.  I've heard that in Excel 365 they are going to bump the max rows to millions per sheet, but I'd still suggest breaking things up so it doesn't take forever.