# Export to Excel does not render in SharePoint for large files

Tags: excel, sharepoint, reporting-services

I have an SSRS report that has 50 columns and ~77,000 rows when run for a Plant (Distribution Center). This report shows inventory and relating statistics (which is why it is so large). When i attempt to export this from SharePoint it hangs for a very long time (<10 minutes) and then responds with *"Sorry something went wrong"*. So i took a look at the file size which is only 3mb. I did some digging online and found that SharePoint has a maximum file size limit when exporting (our config file was set at 4mb). So i had our SharePoint administrator take a look. He increased the size to 10mb and the file still has the same exporting problem. I ran the same report for a different distribution center (with significantly less data. About 2000 rows) and the report exports fine. I set my report up as a subscription and the report export also fails. So i am wondering if there is a setting in the reporting server or SharePoint that will fix this issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is a limitation on the Excel side and not the SSRS/Sharepoint side if you are using SSRS 2008r2 or less.  The maximum number of rows you can export to Excel is 65,536.

SSRS 2012, included with SQL server 2012 will remove this limit: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/farukcelik/archive/2012/02/01/sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-reporting-services-in-sql-server-2012-codename-quot-denali-quot-will-support-xlsx-docx-formats-bye-bye-65536-rows-limit-in-xls-files.aspx

The workaround for 2008R2 and before is to export as .csv

Credit to [This Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9682170/excel-export-fail-when-number-of-rows-in-the-excel-sheet-exceeded-the-limit-of-6)

Comment: Welcome to SO, @Daniel.  Links die and this might get flagged as Low Quality.  Usually when we include links, we include the relevant parts of those links as quotes in the answer just in case the link breaks in the future.

Comment: This is not the same issue. To test, i created a generic report and generated 75000 rows (With only one column). Deployed the report ran it and exported it (Export went fine). We are using SQL Server 2012 and the version of our report server is 2008r2 or newer (Do not have exact version because our admin is out and i do not have security rights). All of our files are exported in EXCELOPENXML rendering format and we are using Excel 2013 (v. 15.0.4675.1000) 64Bit. Thank you for the reply.

Comment: This limitation **does not seem** to be removed from **SSRS 2012**. I am having the same issue when exporting from SSRS from SharePoint. When the report has less that 65k rows, it exports to Excel fine. Otherwise I get the totally useless **Something Went Wrong** message with a link to a dead Microsoft help page.

Answer (score 0):

I spoke with a microsoft support rep and they had us go in and change the httpRuntime line in all the web.config files for _vti_bin and _layout and for our IIS site to contain an executiontimout = 3000600. This was just simply a timeout issue but had to be applied to every server in our farm for the report to render. Just thought i would put this up for anyone who runs into this issue in the future.