# Maximum number of rows in excel while exporting using lotus script

Tags: excel, lotus-notes, export-to-excel, lotus-domino, lotusscript

I have created a lotus script agent which exports documents from a view. The number of documents are approximately 70000. When I run the agent it terminates exactly at 65536 th row. So my guess is that the maximum number of rows allowed in an excel worksheet is 65,536. But microsoft site says that the max rows allowed are nearly 1 lakh (100,000). So what could possibly the issue?

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-in/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa?CorrelationId=c3f81a7d-61f6-4a29-adff-10d481d2ea7f&ui=en-US&rs=en-IN&ad=IN

P.S.. I use excel 2007.

Comment: Does your excel say compatibility mode in the title? If so, you can save the file as a new style file under the "save as" menu, or change your default to always use the 2007 file standard. (copied from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197762/is-it-possible-to-see-more-than-65536-rows-in-excel-2007)

Comment: I believe you have ot specify an .xlsx file format in your code in order to get the larger limit. I'm not sure if it's automatic from the filename that you use, or if there's more that you have to do in order to avoid getting a default .xls format. It might help if you showed your code.

Answer (score 0):

> 65536

Yep, that's the exact maximum number of rows in an Excel sheet. Whoever told you it was a good idea to use Excel to handle such an amount of data fooled you.

Comment: Incorrect information. Modern (2007+) versions have a limit of 1,048,576

https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-gb/article/Excel-specifications-and-limits-16c69c74-3d6a-4aaf-ba35-e6eb276e8eaa?CorrelationId=f484b46d-6899-47fb-894a-ac83cd195132&ui=en-US&rs=en-GB&ad=GB

Answer (score 0):

Does your agent as a row counter? if so , is it's type integer or long ?