# Alasql: Is there a maximum limit for the data size?

Tags: javascript, alasql

I try to load my xlsx file and it contains about 200,000 rows. When I use the code to load the file:

```
alasql.promise('SELECT * FROM XLSX("' + fileUrl + '")')
            .then(function (res) {console.log(res)});
```

It only show 65535 records of the arrays. What could I do if I want to load all data? Thank you!

Comment: 66535 or 65535? 65535 was the old max number of line for excel

Comment: Thank you for your reply Fefux, yes it is 65535. I am already using 2007 xlsx but it still load 65535 line...

Comment: And if you open your xlsx with excel, it shows all rows?

Comment: yes it show all rows~

Answer (score -1):

Excel up to 2003 : an Excel worksheet is limited to 65535 lines.

In 2007: an Excel worksheet is limited to is 1,048,576 lines.

So I think you should try 2007 version.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Vinh Vu~ I am already using 2007 xlsx but it still load 65535 line...

Comment: This link can help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197762/is-it-possible-to-see-more-than-65536-rows-in-excel-2007

Comment: Thank you Vinh Vu, I can see more than 65535 in xslx. but it only load 65535 rows data...