# spreadsheet excel reader not reading sheet if it has data on row 65536

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, spreadsheet, phpexcelreader

I am trying to read spreadsheet(.xls) using spreadsheet_excel_reader. My code is a below :

```
<?php
require_once 'Excel/reader.php';
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->read('test.xls');
echo $data->sheets[0]['numRows'];die;
?>
```

this returns number of row till where the data is. If there is any data on row 65536 the it returns 0. Actual return value should be 65536. Is there any fix or work around for this ?

Comment: Have you seen this yet? https://stackoverflow.com/q/197762/1415724 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/4895230/1415724 or https://github.com/iliaal/php_excel/issues/13 - Sounds like you've hit the limit.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Thanks for reply with links .. so what is the bottom line here ?

Comment: yes, the limit is till 65536, but the spreadsheet allows us to write on 65536 row then it should also allow us to read the data on 65536 row.

Comment: Welcome. TBH, I won't be able to provide you with a solution. I Google'd the error to see possible solutions for you to look into. Let's see if someone else can help you with this. However, go through those Q&A's and see if those will help you, there should be something in there that may provide a solution.

Comment: I'm not familiar with php, but if you can somehow check if there is data in first row, but the result is 0, then you know the right value is the worksheet limit (65536 in this case).

Comment: `PHPExcel` !== `Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader`

Answer (score 0):

I probably did not get the point but this could be due to the fact, that the first line starts with 1 in Excel while it starts with 0 in most coded implementations. So if you have 10 lines in Excel you have indexes from 0-9 = 10 values!